# Why does it say "can't find constructor" in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class ring {
private:
    T *m_values;
    int m_size;
    int m_index;

public:
    class iterator;

public:
    ring(int size):
            m_size(size), m_index(0), m_values(NULL) {
        m_values = new T[size];
    }

    ~ring() {
        delete [] m_values;
     }

    int size() const {
        return m_size;
    }

    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(0, *this);
    }

    iterator end() {
        return iterator(m_size, *this);
    }

    void add(T value) {
        m_values[m_index] = value;
        m_index = (m_index + 1) % m_size;
    }

    T &get(int pos) {
        return m_values[pos];
    }
};

template<class T>
class ring<T>::iterator {
private:
     int m_pos;
     ring &m_ring;
public:
    iterator(int m_pos, ring &m_ring): m_pos(m_pos), m_ring(m_ring) {};

    iterator &operator++(int) {
        m_pos++;
        return *this;
    }

    iterator &operator++() {
        m_pos++;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(const iterator &other) {
        return other.m_pos != m_pos;
    }

    T &operator*() {
        return m_ring.get(m_pos);
    }
};
```

Here is the c++ code. I am new to c++ and this codes at CLion gives me "Class iterator doesn't have a constructor iterator(int,ring)" at begin() and end() function. Can anone give me some hint about why this would happen even I have defined it?

BTW: This is from udemy "Learn Advanced C++ Programming" lecture 44.

UPDATE: Some comments find I didn't define and only declare. That's not the reason because I defined it in a separate .cpp file. I also tried to define it inline but still give me the same error message from CLion.

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error or an IDE error? Assuming that iterator constructor is actually defined somewhere this should compile fine.

Answer (score 5):

You **declare** the constructor here

```
iterator(int m_pos, ring &m_ring);
```

but there is no **definition** of this special member function. If you provide one, you're probably fine

```
iterator(int m_pos, ring &m_ring) : m_pos(m_pos), m_ring(m_ring)
{
    /* Maybe some other stuff... */
}
```

Comment: Doesn't feel like the right answer to me. It's a compiler error, not a linking error. Problem is the order of declarations I think. iterator has only been forward declared at the point it is being used,

Comment: @john It compiles fine without linking. The CLion message does indeed look like a compilation issue, but that might simply be misleading.

Comment: sorry about that, I've defined the constructor exactly the way you did but still getting the same compile issue.

Answer (score 0):

You **declared** the interator(int, ring) but not **defined** it. That is the problem.

*Declaration vs Definition*:

> A declaration provides basic attributes of a symbol: its type and its
>   name. A definition provides all of the details of that symbol--if it's
>   a function, what it does; if it's a class, what fields and methods it
>   has; if it's a variable, where that variable is stored. Often, the
>   compiler only needs to have a declaration for something in order to
>   compile a file into an object file, expecting that the linker can find
>   the definition from another file. If no source file ever defines a
>   symbol, but it is declared, you will get errors at link time
>   complaining about undefined symbols.

src: https://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html

Comment: its better to correct the code given in the question.

Comment: I tried to define the constructor in the header file and cpp file, it always shows that "compile" issue.